# opening writable '<pipe' of perl module IPC::Run hangs

Tags: perl

I am learning perl module IPC::Run. while reading the cpan doc, I came across `'<pipe'`. I wrote  a small program. On execution it always hangs.

Code I have written :  which is just a copy from cpan doc.

```
local (*IN);
@cat = ('cat') 
$h = start \@cat, '<pipe', \*IN;
   print IN "hello world\n";
   pump $h;
   close IN;
   finish $h;
```

Any idea why it hangs? what I am missing in this?

Thank,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `pump` says "it blocks until it delivers some input or recieves some output."

It doesn't make sense to call `pump` in that example. `start` wasn't given anything to deliver, and `start` wasn't instructed to listen to `cat`.

Remove that line.